Ansible running a query extracting a `time without time zone` object raises `TypeError: Value of unknown type: <type 'datetime.date'>`
I am writing an ansible playbook.
I have the following task
- name: query on server_app - look for items_invoiced
  community.postgresql.postgresql_query:
    login_host: '{{ db_host }}'
    login_user: '{{ db_username }}'
    login_password: '{{ db_password }}'
    db: '{{ db_database }}'
    port: '{{ db_database_port }}'
    query: "{{ lookup('template', 'extract_items_invoiced__hourly.sql.j2') }}"

  register: items_invoiced

the content of extract_items_invoiced__hourly.sql.j2 is
select hour_payment, * from my_table

where my_table.hour_payment is a time without time zone object.
As the playbook runs, the following Traceback is raised
query on server_app - look for items_invoiced...
Using module file /home/my_user/var/NTTDATA/4store/ansible-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py
Pipelining is enabled.
<10.133.4.100> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: my_user
<10.133.4.100> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="/home/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="my_user"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/my_user/.ansible/cp/a7034d48db 10.133.4.100 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.133.4.100> (1, b'', b'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "<stdin>", line 102, in <module>\n  File "<stdin>", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n  File "<stdin>", line 40, in invoke_module\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 188, in run_module\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\n  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py", line 524, in <module>\n  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py", line 520, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2200, in exit_json\n  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2193, in _return_formatted\n  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 420, in remove_values\n  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 397, in _remove_values_conditions\nTypeError: Value of unknown type: <type \'datetime.date\'>, 2024-04-17\n')
<10.133.4.100> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 102, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
  File "<stdin>", line 40, in invoke_module
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 188, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py", line 524, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py", line 520, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2200, in exit_json
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2193, in _return_formatted
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 420, in remove_values
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 397, in _remove_values_conditions
TypeError: Value of unknown type: <type 'datetime.date'>, 2024-04-17
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 102, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
  File "<stdin>", line 40, in invoke_module
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 188, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py", line 524, in <module>
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py", line 520, in main
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2200, in exit_json
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 2193, in _return_formatted
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 420, in remove_values
  File "/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 397, in _remove_values_conditions
TypeError: Value of unknown type: <type 'datetime.date'>, 2024-04-17
  server_app failed: {
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 102, in <module>\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 40, in invoke_module\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 188, in run_module\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py\", line 524, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/postgresql/plugins/modules/postgresql_query.py\", line 520, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 2200, in exit_json\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 2193, in _return_formatted\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 420, in remove_values\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload_pOF_WY/ansible_community.postgresql.postgresql_query_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py\", line 397, in _remove_values_conditions\nTypeError: Value of unknown type: <type 'datetime.date'>, 2024-04-17\n",
    "module_stdout": "",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 1
}

So ansible is telling me that its python modules cannot recognize the datetime.date type
TypeError: Value of unknown type: <type 'datetime.date'>, 2024-04-17

could it be that there is a bug in the library?
I have searched on the internet and found this thread where the same error is pointed out, however it seems that the problem was fixed in ansible version 2.9, while my ansible version is already ansible [core 2.11.12], so , why I am still running into the issue?
For the moment, I have solved by casting the time without time zone to TEXT via sql
select hour_payment::text, * from my_table


In that github issue, they're using Python 3, while your traceback suggest you're still on Python 2.7, which is pretty outdated by now. No idea if that's the issue here, just the old Python 2 jumping into my eyes ;-)
